# Android Studio 404 Not found error with code that works in any other IDE

Tags: java, android, api, http-status-code-404

I am attempting to use an API in android studio. The code works in pure java but gives the 404 error when used in Android Studio. The domain is removed in this code but it does fully work in a standard java IDE (Unchanged!).

```
URL url = new URL("<domain>");
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
http.setRequestMethod("GET");
http.setDoOutput(true);
http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + email + ":" + wachtwoord);
http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
http.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");

System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());
```

With output

```
I/System.out: 404 Not Found
```

What could be the problem causing this?
Thanks in advance

```
URL url = new URL("<domain>");
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
http.setRequestMethod("GET");
http.setDoOutput(true);
http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + email + ":" + wachtwoord);
http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
http.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");

System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());
```

With output

```
I/System.out: 404 Not Found
```

I expected this code to work as it does fully work in a standard java IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This code works on Android Studio (change your server URL):

```java
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.*;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      URL url = new URL("https://localhost:6240");
      HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      http.setRequestMethod("GET");
      http.setDoOutput(true);
      http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
      http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + "e@e" + ":" + "ww");
      http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
      http.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");

      System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

`printStackTrace` will help you what you are missing with authorization in your IDE/env.

Comment: Highly recommend [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection)